# Make sure a string literal union belongs to an object's keys

Tags: typescript

```
export type A = "a" | "b" | "c";

const obj = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 };
```

How do I make sure all elements of `A` are keys of object `obj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you need, you can automatically construct your type:

### All keys as a type

You can use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-extraction.html#the-keyof-type-operator) to have all the keys as a union. Since `keyof` needs to be used on a type, the `keyof typeof obj`:

```typescript
const obj = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 };

export type A = keyof typeof obj; // "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBDAXDALADQzx4CsxweAbMQCZ4DsMAvgNwBQHApgB4AOIAE6woAT37cYAQVQwA1tzEgAZjHGTVcJJyA)

### Remove some of the keys

You can then [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) some of the keys and get the rest:

```typescript
const obj = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 };
type AllKeys = keyof typeof obj;
export type A = Exclude<AllKeys, "d">; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBDAXDALADQzx4CsxweAbMQCZ4DsMAvgNwBQUAngA4CmMAIIAbEQGl+3CKhgBrKSABmMHgOVwknfgA9eIAE6w1gobICiO4CICudfgB5REqRGIAiOu4B8bIA)

the `AllKeys` type is just for convenience, you can inline it and use `Exclude<keyof typeof obj, "d">`

### Only allow some of the keys

This would be sort of the opposite of `Exclude` - instead of blacklisting keys, you have a whitelist and only pick keys that exist in it using [an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types):

```typescript
const obj = { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 };
type AllKeys = keyof typeof obj;
type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b" | "c" | "y" | "z";
export type A = AllKeys & AllowedKeys; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBDAXDALADQzx4CsxweAbMQCZ4DsMAvgNwBQUAngA4CmMAIIAbEQGl+3CKhgBrKSABmMHgOVwknNYNEiQAd351J02QCIs5mAB8Y5+NbvngT+9zfmAXuc78AHrwgAE6wOsKyeqYyAGTCYobG0WxAA)

Again, the two types `AllKeys` and `AllowedKeys` are here for convenience. You can also have the same as `keyof typeof obj & ("a" | "b" | "c" | "y" | "z");`