# What is the TypeScript equivalent of using the bracket and variable which is a string to access an object property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

An interviewer asked me the TypeScript way of doing this:

```js
const foo = { bar: 33, wah: 66 };

console.log(foo.bar);   // 33
console.log(foo.wah);   // 66


let someName = "bar";
console.log(foo[someName]);    //33

someName = "wah";
console.log(foo[someName]);    // 66
```

I searched for the Internet for 10 minutes (which the interviewer allowed) and I found 500 or 1000 word writings and I still don't know how it is done, by seeing an 1 line or 2 line example.  **For the JavaScript code that can use a string to access the property `bar` and `wah`, what is the TypeScript equivalent way of doing it?  Can somebody give a few lines of TypeScript code that can actually run and print out `33` and `66` like the JS code above, but in a TypeScript Playground or something similar to a JSFiddle?**

Comment: The question is really vague, but if you must use `let` (and not `const`) and want to restrict variable to only known object's keys, you can: `let someName: keyof typeof foo = "bar";`

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: It really isn't clear what your interviewer was trying to ask, since this code isn't actually doing anything practical. They could have been looking for any one of a few different answers.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeMBGBDATgLhgGYiAaGAd2wAtCA2OmAXwG4AoN0SEAGwFMAdDxABzABQIQAnLgCULGIoD0S4kU7gIvQcPGSBVavMUwVMBhzb9YWgLZ8ActnuEA1nwCeIODCgeADnze8IgoMABEMuHsXFr8QqISiADado7OfAC6xiYqJBxpTvZh4YbRGtzxukkgqSD2RVnyQA

Comment: @AlekseyL. maybe you can give it as an answer... for the line `let someName: keyof typeof foo = "bar";` What if the property name needs to be (1) 12 names or 20 names? or (2) what if it needs to be totally dynamic (meaning it could be anything dynamically)? Seems like it does: https://tsplay.dev/vWkQJN

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a bad question for interview because it is too open. Anyway, you can restrict `someName` to either be "bar" or "wah", like this:

```ts
const foo = { bar: 33, wah: 66 };

console.log(foo.bar);   // 33
console.log(foo.wah);   // 66

// Only this line changed.
let someName: "bar"|"wah" = "bar";

console.log(foo[someName]);    //33

someName = "wah";
console.log(foo[someName]);    // 66
```

[TSPlayground link](https://tsplay.dev/lWYOxN)

When you change the `let someName` to not assign any type to it, by default it assumes it `string` type, which could be anything. So, when you restrict it to union of two string literals that are also the keys of the object, the warning goes away.

Comment: Also an option `let someName: keyof typeof foo` but it really depends on what the specific goal is. As you say, the question is too open ended.

Comment: I think that's a better option.

Comment: is the code you gave in the Playground `let someName: "bar"|"wah" = "bar";` already fully TS? It looked very much JS except this line `let someName: "bar"|"wah" = "bar";`. What if the property name needs to be (1) 12 names or 20 names?  or (2) what if it needs to be totally dynamic (meaning it could be anything dynamically)?

Comment: @deeper-understanding "*What if the property name needs to be (1) 12 names or 20 names?*" `keyof typeof foo` will cover all valid keys for `foo`. You can [perform some type arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377634/) if you want a subsection of the keys. "*(2) what if it needs to be totally dynamic (meaning it could be anything dynamically)*" then you're back at your initial question - in your case `someName` would be typed as `string` and then TS will raise an error because you might be trying to access `foo["xyz"]` which is not known to exist.

Comment: @deeper-understanding 1. It is fully TS, `foo` is automatically inferred to be of type `{bar: number; wah: number;}`, 2. The reason I called this open ended is exactly because question itself is open to discussion, if you want it to support any number of attributes and just not `bar` and `wah`, you should use `let someName: keyof typeof foo` as suggested above.

Comment: I guess he was just hoping to see how familiar I am with TS

Answer (score 1):

By default, Typescript uses the "most specific" possible type to represent a given value. In the case of `{ bar: 33, wah: 66 }`, the type is `{ bar: number, wah: number}`. This means that no other fields are allowed.

But Typescript also has a way to represent other types of values, where an object has a key of some other type. The syntax for this is:

```js
type MyMap = { [myKey: string]: number };
```

The type allowed for the key is any subtype of `string | number`. So the following would also be valid:

```
type MyKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type MyMap = { [key: MyKeys]: number };
```

Typescript also has a built in type for this - `Record<Key, Value>`:

```
const someString = "blah";
const myMap: Record<string, number> = { bar: 33, wah: 66 };
// can then be accessed with any key
myMap[someString];
```

Comment: `Record<string, any>` would be more apt, imo.

Comment: Does `Map` in TS refer to [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of js or is it for generic objects?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant `Record`. `map` is the name I used to use for my own version of it before it was added to TS :) I'll edit the answer.

Comment: can you give me perhaps the TypeScript snippet, if it can be in some TypeScript playground or similar to a JSFiddle site that can actually run?

Comment: @deeper-understanding [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGAlApqATgEwDzRYCWYA5gDQxgCuAtgEbpYB8MAvDAN4z0CGWKAMyDKAd14ALFADZpMAL4BuAFDLQkEABt0AOk0hSACgQgdfLAEpFMGwHpbMYWvAQtu-UZM7xEqzZj2MLKqytqwrrToAHK8kewwAETmCSrqrtp6BsaIANoR0bHoALp+-vZOyvkxcRwJPinOGhke2SB5IJHVxaV2DrJAA) - you can click **Run** - it's above the code area to the left.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned TypeScript considers keys of the `foo` object to be equal to `'bar'` or `'wah'`, but the variable `someName` is a general type: `string`. So here comes the error, since `'bar'` and `'wah'` are not just `string`, but they are exactly `'bar'` or `'wah'` strings. The error could be fixed by redefining the type of the object defining that it has keys of type `string`.

```js
const foo: {
    [key: string]: number
} = { bar: 33, wah: 66 };

console.log(foo.bar);   // 33
console.log(foo.wah);   // 66


let someName = "bar";
console.log(foo[someName]);    //33

someName = "wah";
console.log(foo[someName]);    // 66
```

This way TypeScript knows that any string could by used as a key for this object. While this is fine in some cases, sometimes we should be sure that our object allows only keys it actually is defined with. Then you should implicitly set type of the key that your're trying to use to the exact values, like `'bar'` or `'wah'`. See Nishant's answer