# Is there a method to directly exclude types from a union type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want exclude function types from a given union type.

```
type T = number | string | VoidFunction;  // a GIVEN type

type R = ExcludeType<T, VoidFunction>;  // number | string
```

I found I can achieve it by adding a tool function like:

```
type T = number | string | VoidFunction;  // a GIVEN type

function f(v: T) {
  if (v instanceof Function) return undefined;
  return v;
}

type R = typeof f;  // number | string
```

But I think it's complex and unexpandable, and I can't use it in '.d.ts' files either.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - why doesn't `Exclude` work for you? Also, just in case it's relevant, check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377634) which shows how to get a subsection of a union type in two ways - subtraction (with `Exclude`) and an intersection with another union type (with `&`).

Answer (score 8):

It is just [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion):

```
type R = Exclude<T, VoidFunction>;  // number | string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UB2BXAtgIwgJygHygGdhsBLJAc3ygDUB7UgEwDEUkBjYUupAbiigB6QVACGUAOIBJGgFEAclFCQAUCuXQASgiiyAHuwA2KRhAA8MADS0GLNp25IAfPyEjUmHNWJlKQA)

---

> `Exclude<Type, ExcludedUnion>`

> Constructs a type by excluding from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `ExcludedUnion`.